# When I am decrypting a text file the text file becomes empty

Tags: c#, windows, encryption

guys, I'm new to this website and I'm a really new to programming any help would be awesome! Thanks Below are my code for encryption and decryption. Images and PDF files get encrypted and decrypted no problems, but text files I don't know it's not showing anything in the file after decryption.

```
   private void encrypt (string input, string output, string strHash )

{
    FileStream inStream, outStream;
    CryptoStream CryStream;

    TripleDESCryptoServiceProvider TDC = new TripleDESCryptoServiceProvider();
    MD5CryptoServiceProvider md5 = new MD5CryptoServiceProvider();

    byte[] byteHash, byteTexto;

    inStream = new FileStream(input, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
    outStream = new FileStream(output, FileMode.OpenOrCreate, FileAccess.Write);

    byteHash = md5.ComputeHash(ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes(strHash));
    byteTexto = File.ReadAllBytes(input);

    md5.Clear();enter code here

    TDC.Key = byteHash;
    TDC.Mode = CipherMode.ECB;

    CryStream = new CryptoStream(outStream, TDC.CreateEncryptor(), CryptoStreamMode.Write);

    int bytesRead;
    long length, position = 0;
    length = inStream.Length;

    while(position < length)
    {
        bytesRead = inStream.Read(byteTexto, 0, byteTexto.Length);
        position += bytesRead;

        CryStream.Write(byteTexto, 0, bytesRead);

    }

    inStream.Close();
    outStream.Close();
}

private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

}

private void btnDecrypt_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    OpenFileDialog open = new OpenFileDialog();
    open.ShowDialog();

    txtLocalDecFile.Text = open.FileName;

    SaveFileDialog save = new SaveFileDialog();
    save.ShowDialog();

    txtNewDecFile.Text = save.FileName;

    decrypt(txtLocalDecFile.Text, txtNewDecFile.Text, key);

}

private void decrypt(string input, string output, string strHash)
{
    FileStream inStream, outStream;
    CryptoStream CryStream;
    TripleDESCryptoServiceProvider TDC = new TripleDESCryptoServiceProvider();
    MD5CryptoServiceProvider md5 = new MD5CryptoServiceProvider();

    byte[] byteHash, byteTexto;

    inStream = new FileStream(input, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
    outStream = new FileStream(output, FileMode.OpenOrCreate, FileAccess.Write);

    byteHash = md5.ComputeHash(ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes(strHash));
    byteTexto = File.ReadAllBytes(input);

    md5.Clear();

    TDC.Key = byteHash;
    TDC.Mode = CipherMode.ECB;

    CryStream = new CryptoStream(outStream, TDC.CreateDecryptor(), CryptoStreamMode.Write);

    int bytesRead;
    long length, position = 0;
    length = inStream.Length;

    while (position < length)
    {
        bytesRead = inStream.Read(byteTexto, 0, byteTexto.Length);
        position += bytesRead;

        CryStream.Write(byteTexto, 0, bytesRead);

    }

    inStream.Close();
    outStream.Close();
}
```

Comment: Aside: What's with the unused `strHash`/`byteHash`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You forgot to close your CryptoStream which means that it could not flush all data to the file.

Either close the stream like you do with inStream and outStream or call FlushFinalBlock() on CryStream.

There is an [example](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.tripledescryptoserviceprovider(v=vs.110).aspx) in the documentation.

Comment: An unhandled exception of type 'System.ObjectDisposedException' occurred in mscorlib.dll when i inserted CryStream.close();

Comment: I literally dont even have any error handling too im soo bad.. im going to have to learn how to do that.

Answer (score 0):

Try use AES encryption:

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/769741/Csharp-AES-bits-Encryption-Library-with-Salt

There is an example of how to encrypt and decrypt